# Which text needs to be filtered from User Submitted Data?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input, filter

I'm trying to put together some PHP validation functions to screen user-submitted form data for any characters, or strings, that would be potential security risks. I've taken the steps I'm aware of, which are listed below, but I'm looking to make sure that I'm not overlooking anything!

The user supplied data is filtered as follows:

- For integers I check if ctype_digit() is true or false
- For other numbers, which may include decimals, I use is_numeric()
- For emails I use filter_var() and FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL
- For IP Addresses I use filter_var() and FILTER_VALIDATE_IP
- For URLs I use filter_var() and FILTER_VALIDATE_URL
- For HTML code I use strip_tags() while allowing: p, a, b, br, font, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, i, li, ol, span, ul, strong, div, img, article, section, header, footer, aside, details, figcaption, figure, main, mark, nav, summary, time, pre, hr, style, svg, path
- For an RGBA I use filter_var() with FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP and the following regex: '/^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]),){3}(0(.[0-9]+)?|1(.0+)?)$/'
- For validating a timestamp I check if it's an integer - and if so pass it to the date(). If it's not an integer I see if DateTime::createFromFormat() can interpret it

All data is inserted / updated to MySql using prepared statements. All non-numeric user-submitted data is output to the browser using htmlentities($val,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')

As of right now, the user-submitted text can include names, addresses, emails, urls, phone numbers, rgba values -- also paragraphs which potentially include html formatting such as < div class="paragraphtext"style="width:10rem">< h1>Header< /h1>Some paragraph text....can include: punctuation (even parenthesis)?!< /div>

What I'm missing, in my mind, is something to filter regular text submitted by a user for any unsafe characters or strings...but I'm not sure what they would be. Is using prepared statements / htmlentities enough - or is there something else I should be doing? Also - are any of my current filters incorrect?

UPDATE::

For now I decided to use filter_var() with FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP for all other text not already handled with the above filters. The regex allows for any punctuation I can reasonably think of being used in the paragraphs. From what I know, using the prepared statements and htmlentities should alleviate any problems I would have with characters like the quotes, slashes, etc - so I'm hoping this is good?  Any feedback would be great.  For what it's worth to anyone who finds this, I am also using using preg_replace to spit out a list of characters that violate the regex - that way I can let the user know which characters are invalid. I'm also using some array functions with it to filter out duplicate characters. The code is:

```
$rgx='[a-zA-Z0-9!#%&:;=@~"\'\/\\\^\*\-\_\.\?\+\(\)\$\s]';
  if(!filter_var($val,FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,array('options'=>array('regexp'=>'/^'.$rgx.'+$/'))))
{

return'Error! May not contain '.implode(' ',array_unique(str_split(preg_replace('/'.$rgx.'/','',$val))));

}
```

Comment: That's entirely depending on the context. If you are in a html context, you want be sure that you've converted all the special chars that have some meaningful into HTML entities; if you're output something in an attribute, or js var, etc. you need to do some other consideration; using prepared statements instead of just escape the contents and put it in the query it's perfectly fine - the rest is upon your application needs (i.e you want be sure that the user's email is really an email, before store it, or that its birthday does not fall on the empy string "" provided by the user, and so on)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, using filter_var() and FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL should make sure emails are at least correctly formatted - and I believe that passing dates through date() and DateTime::createFromFormat() should make sure they are valid dates.  I believe that outputting text in the format of htmlentities($val,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8') as I had mentioned covers "all the special chars that have some meaningful into HTML entities" - right?

Comment: Data is submitted by users through forms on our website, processed with PHP, stored in the MySql database, retrieved using PHP and displayed - potentially - in various places in the user's account, or on html documents generated from user-submitted html code and/or text paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "universal filtering / validation method" for what you are looking for. You always have to validate and escape the data in the specific context you use the data.

**Important note:** Don't use filtering, use explicit validation and whitelisting instead.

**Examples:**

- You enter the data into a database, use (as you already do) prepared statements (that's the best... well, or at least escape them).
- You output user input as HTML output again, use `htmlentites()` (against XSS attacks).
- You call a shell command (e.g. for compressing images or processing specific csv files), then use `escapeshellcmd()` and `escapeshellarg()`, etc.
- If you want to validate if an e-mail address is correct, please don't write your own regex, instead use an existing validation class.
  Etc.